# Can 'egalitarian' be used for gender bias also?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

*Egalitarian* is typically used when discussing equality in political, social, economic and civil issues. Can it also be used to portray equality in gender issues? E.g. an egalitarian does not discriminate on the basis of gender, or favor one gender more than the other.

Comment: gender is a social and economic issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egalitarianism)
provides an example of use of egalitarian towards gender.

> The Christian egalitarian view holds
>   that the Bible teaches the *fundamental
>   equality of women* and men of all
>   racial and ethnic mixes...

Every now and then I have seen reputed print media referring to men who strive for female causes as egalitarian. For example note the use of egalitarian for gender equality [here](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2010-07-19/education/28297363_1_global-citizens-countries-france).

I believe it can be (and often is) used for gender equality.

Answer (score 10):

Of course.

> **Egalitarian**, *adj.* - of, relating to, or believing in the principle **that all people are equal** and deserve equal rights and opportunities.

If all people are equal, that includes gender, race, religion, status, etc.

Comment: Indeed, I'd say that the *primary* sense of "egalitarian" is gender-related for me, these days.

Comment: but would you call a person 'egalitarian' if the person does not discriminate on basis of gender only... lets say, an organization can be called egalitarian if it does not recruit people on basis of gender?

Comment: @amit It could be they recruit people on a gender basis, if they note they have less people of that gender in their organization.